# Why does adding a series to a JavaFX LineChart take so long

Tags: javafx, linechart

I'm trying to add and remove series to a chart in real time to create breaks in my data and to add new points. Each add / remove of the series in the chart take roughly 300ms, which is forever in computing terms.

The functionality I'm going for is to create a chart that looks like this:
[image]

Each time a I have a program which adds and removes the series and it outputs the following information. I am in the FX application thread and anything that takes longer than ~50ms on that thread make the display very jumpy.

```
time between calls: 1388ms 
dataUpdateTime: 4ms series updated: 3 points added: 83 points removed: 105
seriesAddTime: 3719ms series added 4 
seriesRemoveTime: 3719ms series removed 0
total update time: 3719ms
```

Adding data to existing series is very fast, maybe there is a way to tell the series to add a break in the data?

Comment: Maybe first you have to ask yourself if this is the best chart to display your data? Second, if you add a whole series, how many data items is it containing? Have you switched animation off for testing purposes? If you add a lot of data to your chart you should do it in another thread and not on the FX-Mainthread.

Comment: I thought that it may be related to amount of data I'm adding into the series but the lag shows up even when I add the empty series. Adding data to those empty series is very cheap once they are in the chart.

Comment: The data actually renders smoother with the animations turned on, the FX thread isn't held up.

I thought about the other FXCharts but I didn't see one that fits better. The only operations I'm doing on the main thread are adding the blank series using addAll and updating the series data (which is very fast).

Comment: Can you please add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?. So it is more possible to help you.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add one when I get back into the office on Monday. I thought maybe someone would know the answer with out one.